# safe place to download amdxata.sys file for Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot

Windows 7 won't load up on my Dell Studio XPS 1340 and system repair says "boot critical file amdxata.sys is corrupt". Someone in the post below just replaced this file with another in the same folder but I don't have the file mentioned in my folder:

[Windows 7 boot failure after update](https://superuser.com/questions/275843/windows-7-boot-failure-after-update)

Is there a safe place to download amdxata.sys from? There are a few free DLL fixer programs on the net but they probably only work in Windows and not CMD which is all I have access to. Also some say they aren't safe programs. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try copying the file off a friend's computer with the same operating system. I don't believe Windows provide the raw system file for the end user to download individually.

Meaning to say, otherwise, you would just have to google and find an uploaded file online such as this [site](http://www.dll-files.com/).

Your other option would be to run the recovery tool through a Windows disc image. All necessary system files should be on it and the tool will patch up what is missing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try to get it off another computer. When I have it say on a USB key any idea of the command I would use in Command Prompt to copy the file from the USB to the Windows folder? I've tried the Dell Windows installation CD and it won't repair the file. That website you linked to is the sort of site I've read which contains viruses etc.

Comment: Try launching to command prompt before boot to make the changes: http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2880-command-prompt-boot-open-windows-10-a.html

Comment: I am not actually sure if a USB drive will be read before Windows loads up. If not, you would be unable to load the file either way. You could try booting a portable linux pendrive, and modify the filesystem from it.

Comment: I think you're right about the USB. I have Hiren's boot disc with mini XP on a CD so I'll use that to transfer the file. Thanks again.